# Error when using greek symbol in subscript in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, fonts, errors

I am working on a beamer presentation which will include many mathematical symbols. I use MiKTeX 2.9 and the TeXstudio IDE.

I have run into a problem when I attempt to use certain mathematical symbols. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is normal text
    \item This item has a greek symbol: $\alpha$
    \item This item uses it as a subscript $C_\alpha$
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I use `\alpha` twice, once normally and once in a subscript. However, this only compiles without the third item. If that is included, this produces the error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file mathkerncmssi10): Font mathkerncmssi10 at 657
 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have made a web search for similar error texts and found nothing. I have no idea how to further proceed, and would appreciate any hints at what is actually going wrong.

#### Update 1

It seems this is not related to the `\alpha` symbol at all, but instead just caused by any letters I try to typeset in mathmode. Including

```
\item $a$
```

already causes this error and fails to produce any output document.

Comment: i can't reproduce the problem.  instead of the error you receive, my attempt results in this warning: "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available  (Font)   size <5> substituted on input line 12.".  (i'm still running with tex live 2012, and it's possible that some font names have changed.)  i would interpret the error you got to mean that you don't have type 1 (outline) fonts, only bitmaps.

Comment: If I compile the code you wrote, I don't get any error and the pdf produced looks perfect. You should provide a MWE, i.e. a code that reproduces that error. Surely you're loading some font that causes the problem.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis This *exact* code results in the error I described in my system.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, would you have any idea on what I could try to do to fix it? I have searched the MiKTeX repository for the "mathkerncmssi" and "mathkerncmssi10" fonts without success. In my real use case I also don't fiddle with fonts nor themes for beamer, and just go with the default.

Comment: the first thing to do is find out where `mathkerncmssi` is being called.  that may involve looking in your log file and seeing what files are being reported.  it's actually likely that it's a composite name, with `mathkern` being specified like `OT1` as reported for my attempt; that seems even more probable based on your edit to the question.  search for just `mathkern`; it'll most likely be a slog, but for a starter, it's not in any `beamer` or "base" latex files.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I tried as you suggested but got overwhelmed by the complexity of LaTeX's font handling rather quickly. In any case, I learned a little thanks to your explanation - a missing font definition at some step in compilation is the trouble - and I solved, or more accurately circumvented the issue by using a package to choose a font explicitly instead of leaving it up to the defaults, as the accepted answer suggested. In time, I do want to learn how font handling works, but as so often, urgent stuff (deadlines) trump important stuff (learning more). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The error message indicates that your system is perhaps not up-to-date (run the update manager (both, admin and user version), and that you need to run on the command line `updmap` to update your map files. Changing the font like in the accepted answers avoids the error but does not solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the answer of @Alder Miguel is not sufficient, try also adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to show LaTeX how to recognize some characters. I have compiled this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item This is normal text
  \item This item has a greek symbol: $\alpha$
  \item This item uses it as a subscript $C_\alpha$
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using this code I´m getting this:

[image]