# I can't compile my beamer file when I insert any equation in it!

Tags: beamer, equations, greek, letters

I'm having some troubles with my beamer presentation. When I insert any equation that involves letters (either greek or latin), My compilation fails. It doesn't matter whether I'm doing this in equation environment or between $$. I just don't what's happening, 'cause it should work normally. Here follows my simplified code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{bm} 

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1.0,0.647,0.0}
\definecolor{darkorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.546,0.0}
\definecolor{sienna}{rgb}{0.627,0.321,0.176}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.50}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}



\title[Blabla]{\mbox{}\\ \vspace{0.1cm} Blabla \vspace{0.5cm} }
\date{\color{navy} Blabla} 
\author[bla, \\ bla]{{ \footnotesize \underline{blabla}, blabla} }
\institute{blabla}
\subject{????}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A abordagem perturbativa}
\framesubtitle{}

Partindo da métrica na forma

\begin{equation}
ds^{2} = -h(r) dt^{2} + h(r)^{-1} dr^{2}+r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2})
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error message displayed at the end of the process was:

> Running miktex-makemf.exe... miktex-makemf: The mathkerncmssi source
>   file could not be found.
>
> Running ttf2pk.exe... miktex-makepk: PK font mathkerncmssi10 could not
>   be created.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences (Font)
>   up to 1.0pt have occurred.
>
> ) (see the transcript file for additional information) !pdfTeX error:
>   pdflatex.exe (file mathkerncmssi10): Font mathkerncmssi10 at 657  not
>   found  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Thanks for supporting!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error from your file.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg! So, can the error reside on the installation of my beamer? or in some other package? I've installed my packages through the "install while compiling" mechanism....

Comment: Please, add the error message to the question, rather than in comments.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250413/error-when-using-greek-symbol-in-subscript-in-beamer-presentation?s=1|0.1212 help? Look at Ulrike Fischer's comment, rather than the answers.

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/beamer-over-miktex-2-9-is-not-working-with-math-environment

Comment: I'll add the error message! I'm trying some answers written there!

Comment: @egreg Thank you a lot mate! The link posted by you here has helped me a lot! I could fix the error by updating my miktex! You're awesome! :D

Comment: So I have closed your question as duplicate. Don't worry about this: for newcomers it's not so easy to find related questions (it's much easier for those who know how the site works and are lucky enough to find the right key for the search). Don't be afraid to ask more questions!